# Post data to server angular $http post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post

```
[
    {
        "name": "AAAAAA",
        "date": "28-03-2016",
    },
    {
        "name": "BBBBBB",
        "date": "20-12-2016",
    },
    {
        "name": "CCCCCC",
        "date": "09-01-2016",
    },
    {
        "name": "DDDDDD",
        "date": "21-07-2016",
    }
]
```

My javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.service('service', function($http, $q){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('names.json').then(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        this.getNames = function() {
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    });
    app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service, $http) {
        var promise = service.getNames();
        promise.then(function (data) {
            $scope.names = data.data;
            console.log($scope.names);
        }
    );
    $scope.postfunction = function(data) {
         $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'serwerUrl' ,
                    data: {"name":$scope.name},
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
                .success(function(data){
                    console.log('data success');
                });
```

HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
        <td>{{name.name}}</td>
        <td>{{name.date}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="postfunction(names)">POST</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What I want do is when I click the button "POST" name.name post to server. I try function postfunction(), but it didn't post to server, in my console everything is ok, but name.name don't post to server.

Comment: Add a `.catch()` method in postFunction and check if there is an error

Comment: you are passing `names` to the function, you name it `data` in your function declaration but then you do `data: {"name":$scope.name}`?

Comment: Are you sure that the API takes content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? It is best to use the Angular default of `application/json`? If you must urlencode the data, use the [$httpParamSerializerJQLike Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

Answer (score 1):

The `$scope.name` you're trying to send isn't defined anywhere.

You'll want to change `names` here into `name`:

```
...
<td><button ng-click="postfunction(name)">POST</button></td>
...
```

and in your `postfunction` ditch `$scope.name` altogether and do this instead (also use .then instead of .success, .success is deprecated):

```
$scope.postfunction = function(name) {
    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'serwerUrl' ,
            data: {"name": name},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .then(function(data){
        console.log('data success');
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok, now i post name, but all name json name.name and name.date, i want only name.name

Comment: Then you replace the `ng-click="postfunction(name)"` with `ng-click="postfunction(name.name)"`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the API takes content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? It is best to use the Angular default of `application/json`? If you must urlencode the data, use the [$httpParamSerializerJQLike Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike).

```
.controller(function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
  //...

  $http({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myData),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });

});
```

-- [AngularJS Param Serializer API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)